# Azure Service Bus 3.2.2 BeginReceive()

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, message-queue, azureservicebus

I need to upgrade our service bus nuget package to 3.2.2 (think the evenprocessor host requires it) but I have always kept our service bus project lib at 2.8.2. This is mainly due to the fact that BeginReceive() and EndReceive() looks to have been removed. Is there any reason or anyway I can easily convert this

```
public void StartReceiving(RecieverCallback callback, TimeSpan waittime, object state = null)
    {
        this._recieverCallback = callback;

        _queueClient = this.MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(QueueName, ReceiveMode);

        // make initial async call
        _asyncresult = _queueClient.BeginReceive(waittime, ReceiveDone, _queueClient);
    }

    public void ReceiveDone(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var tmpClient = result.AsyncState as QueueClient;
                var brokeredMessage = tmpClient.EndReceive(result);
                if (brokeredMessage != null)
                {
                    if (ReceiveMode == ReceiveMode.PeekLock)
                    {
                        brokeredMessage.Complete();
                    }
                    var tmpMessage = brokeredMessage.GetBody<T>();
                    ProcessMessageProperties(tmpMessage, brokeredMessage);

                    _recieverCallback(tmpMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Fatal("ReceiveDone: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // do recieve for next message
        _asyncresult = _queueClient.BeginReceive(ReceiveDone, _queueClient);
    }
```

Image showing the error
[image]

Following image shows what happens if I upgrade servicebus to 3.2.2 which I believe will solve the original error (program running 3.2.2, lib project running 2.8.x)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out see link 
https://gist.github.com/sitereactor/8953583

If anyone has a similar issue, let me know and will post my code but its 95% the same as per the link.